# Notification sometimes not received on Android 11 Firebase Messaging Service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our customer are facing a strange issue that consist of not receiving sometimes push notifications in background after they switched to Android 11.

We never had this problem before, until Android 10 the notification was always sent correctly and received by the user; instead right now we are receiving a lot of reports about this problem.

The only solution we have found so far is to force the user to disable battery optimization on the application, but it's not an elegant solution.

Any tips or solutions on how to reliably solve this problem?

Comment: Do you got the result?

Comment: unfortunately not, no solution so far except for the one written above